# Find a string and add a string before some characters

Tags: regex, linux, shell, sed

I'm trying to find the line and then add some string into it but before some characters. Here is the file :

```
{
    "rpc-port": 1234,
    "rpc-username": "",
    "rpc-whitelist": "123.4.5.2,123.123.123.123,152.125.125.125,12.45.12.45,12.36.45.78,12.69.6.1,12.4.8.95,12.45.45.45",
    "rpc-whitelist-enabled": true
}
```

I expect to add 2 ip in the line where is `rpc-whitelist`. So the final output would be :

```
{
    "rpc-port": 1234,
    "rpc-username": "",
    "rpc-whitelist": "123.4.5.2,123.123.123.123,152.125.125.125,12.45.12.45,12.36.45.78,12.69.6.1,12.4.8.95,12.45.45.45,123.123.123.123,123.123.123.123",
    "rpc-whitelist-enabled": true
}
```

The IP are dynamic so it may change.

I tried with the following command but it will add at the end of the line.

```
sed -i '/^"rpc-whitelist"/ s/$/ 123.123.123.123,123.123.123.123/' settings.json
```

I also thought of deleting the last two characters and insert the new string.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/869886/use-sed-to-replace-part-of-a-string maybe this helps

Comment: It's a replace I'm looking to add a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
sed -i 's/^[[:blank:]]*"rpc-whitelist":[[:blank:]]*"[^"]*/& 123.123.123.123,123.123.123.123/' settings.json
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/2zx5jY)

**Details**

- `^` - matches the start of a line
- `[[:blank:]]*` - 0+ whitespace chars
- `"rpc-whitelist":` - a literal substring
- `[[:blank:]]*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `"` - a `"` char
- `[^"]*` - 0+ chars other than `"`.

The `&` in the replacement pattern pastes back the matched text, so it is not lost during the substitution operation.

Comment: @executable `[:blank:]` is a POSIX character class that matches horizontal whitespace chars. It should be used in a bracket expression to work, so it is `[[:blank:]]`. Actually, you may even use `[[:space:]]` (any whitespace) since `sed` works on a line by line basis. If a shorter `\s` works for you, you may use `\s` (it matches any whitespace).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a proper json parser, e.g. with `jq`:

```
jq --arg ip "123.123.123.123" '."rpc-whitelist" = ."rpc-whitelist" + "," + $ip' infile.json
```

Output:

```json
{
  "rpc-port": 1234,
  "rpc-username": "",
  "rpc-whitelist": "123.4.5.2,123.123.123.123,152.125.125.125,12.45.12.45,12.36.45.78,12.69.6.1,12.4.8.95,12.45.45.45,123.123.123.123",
  "rpc-whitelist-enabled": true
}
```